# Detecting if template was re-rendered due to data context change

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, autorun

Here's a pretty common pattern:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    var selector = {}; // should depend on the current data context
    MyCollection.find(selector).observe({
      // ...
    });
  });
}
```

In general, I want the `selector` value depend on the current data context, which may potentially change, but we all know that the `rendered` routine will not be called again, so I don't even try to mess with that. Instead I hope I could invalidate the computation inside `autorun` by accessing the current data context reactively, which seems to be quite a natural thing to do. However it seems it's not documented anywhere (or I am missing something).

If anyone has an idea how to access the current data context reactively, please share.

Comment: As a style question, why not put this inside `created` instead of `rendered`? are you doing DOM manipulation from the autorun?

Comment: You're right. In general it's probably better to do it in `created` but in my particular usecase I am doing some DOM manipulation, so there's no other options I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Template.currentData()`: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata

I think it does exactly what you are looking for.